# divs floating out of window on resize

Tags: html, resize, window, floating

I want to prevent my divs to float out of the browser window if you resize it. Look at this site, and resize the window, and you will see that the divs is floating out. [See here](http://ain.henricson.net/). What is wrong? I have tried to set the divs inside a wrapper with no luck.
Thank you :)

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/? By the way please don't write only in capital letters that is shouting. And nobody will help a person who shouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of things wrong with this page but heres a few things you should do (some not related to fixing the div issue)

- Put all <link/> && <script/> && <style/> tags in the head for a start.

and the css you need (though you will probably tell me you want something more after you have applied this) is:

```
.content {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  top: 100px;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I know theres a lot of wrong things in the code, but I am a noob :)

Comment: And if it does what you are after remember to mark it as the answer please